# Debug trait not satisfied for Arc Mutex when trying to access inner value

Tags: rust

I'm trying to access the inner value of my `Arc<Mutex<T>>` struct. Based on the answers provided to this question, I thought this would work:

```rust
//Arc Wrapper Struct
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ArcWidget<T: WidgetExt + WidgetBase >(Arc<Mutex<T>>);

impl<T: WidgetExt + WidgetBase> ArcWidget<T>{    
    //provide access to the inner widget
    pub fn widg(&self)->Result<(), T>{
        let lock = Arc::try_unwrap(self.0).expect("Lock still has multiple owners")
        let test = lock.into_inner().expect("Mutex cannot be locked");
        test
    }
    pub fn width(&self)->i32{
        let mut widg = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        widg.width()
    }
}
```

However doing so results in error unsatisfied trait bounds error:

```
the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `Arc<Mutex<T>>: Debug`rustcE0599
```

I tried to impliment the Debug Trait for `ArcWidget<T>`:

```
impl<T:WidgetExt + WidgetBase> std::fmt::Debug for ArcWidget<T>{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Val: {}", "gota  widget")
    }
}
```

Something tells me I might be taking the wrong approach here.

So how might I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Debug` is already implemented both for `Mutex` and `Arc` for `T: Debug`, so the only thing you are missing is a `Debug` bound on T:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ArcWidget<T: WidgetExt + WidgetBase + Debug >(Arc<Mutex<T>>);

impl<T: WidgetExt + WidgetBase + Debug> ArcWidget<T>{    
    //provide access to the inner widget
    pub fn widg(&self)->Result<(), T>{
        let lock = Arc::try_unwrap(self.0).expect("Lock still has multiple owners")
        let test = lock.into_inner().expect("Mutex cannot be locked");
        test
    }
    pub fn width(&self)->i32{
        let mut widg = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        widg.width()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ivan's answer is correct. You just need to add the trait bound `T: Debug` . You will have to implement `Debug` for the type if it isn't implemented.

However, the `Debug` requirement is imposed by the `unwrap` method. So, you can just use `expect` if you don't want to require `T: Debug`.

Comment: Which ```unwrap()``` do you refer to? They ```try_unwrap()```? Aren't we already using expect when we use ```Arc::try_unwrap(self.0).expect("Lock still has multiple owners)```

Comment: ```let lock = self.0.into_inner().unwrap();``` seems to have worked